# How to change default settings when adding new users?

Tags: typo3

I wonder how it is possible to change the default settings for creating new users. At the moment I must remove the “live edit” permission and change the BE language to german for every single user.

I have two groups for my users `AUTHOR` and `MAINAUTHOR`. Members of `AUTHOR` should only have access to the draft workspace and only `MAINAUTHOR`’s members should have the live workspace too. (`MAINAUTHOR` inherits from `AUTHOR` and should add only the live permission.)

I found out that I can use `setup.override.lang = de` in the group options to change the language but I can’t find an equivalent for the live permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default pageTS for your own user via userTS (or for a whole group).

There you can use TCAdefaults to set default values for your be_users table.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/11.5/en-us/PageTsconfig/TcaDefaults.html

Example from TYPO3 Core Docs for pages table

```
# Show newly created pages by default
TCAdefaults.pages.hidden = 0
```

Comment: Thanks. But could you explain where I have to set this?

Comment: As said, pageTS or userTS. This is the configuration text field in the page or be_user(group) record.

Comment: OK, but where do I find them in the backend?

Comment: page record == page properties; be_user records are on the root level (pid=0)

Comment: can you please add a code snippet? Stack Overflow convention: Answers should be useful on their own (especially if the link is broken, which is the case here). "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: without the context, it is also more difficult to replace the broken link to the documentation (which I am trying to do right now).

Comment: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/11.5/en-us/PageTsconfig/TcaDefaults.html the context is TCAdefaults

Answer (score 1):

You could try the extension sys_workflows[1] which was made for these kind of tasks. The extension should work on TYPO3 4.5 but doesn't work on a 6.2beta3 (just tested).

[1] http://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-sys_workflows

Comment: Thanks but I’m using a centralized Typo3 installation and I’m not allowed to install extensions :-(

Comment: The link is broken. Also the extension is outdated (supports none of the currently supported TYPO3 versions): https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/sys_workflows

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the default values in the user TSconfig for new users. All options are described in the user TSconfig manual: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/11.5/en-us/UserTsconfig/Setup.html

Also explained is how to configure user TSconfig in general:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/11.5/en-us/UsingSetting/UserTSconfig.html

Comment: Please add context, for example a code snippet so that the answer is useful on its own. As already commented in the other answer: Stack Overflow convention: Answers should be useful on their own (especially if the link is broken at some point in the future). "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer